# How to tell if certain pre-2015 app is 64 bit?

Tags: ios, applications, 64-bit

As there are quite some rumors, about iOS 11 dropping support for 32 bit apps, I need to know, how to tell if an app is 64-bit. I know, that if it was published after february 2015, or if it was updated after june 2015, it has to have 64-bit support. But the app in question - IPELA Communication Mobile by Sony Corporation - was last updated on June 10th 2015. How can i be absolutely sure, that - just in case the rumors come true - I can still use it?

Comment: I'll assume you're ruling out contacting the vendor of specific apps for support and want to know a way you can measure or determine this?

Comment: I did not rule it out, but I can't find any support on SONY website, that is responsible for their mobile apps.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way for me is to install the app on iOS 10.3 (or later) device.

Then open the settings app.

- tap general
- tap About
- tap Applications

iOS will report on the possibility to update all 32 bit apps you have installed on the device by letting you tap to each entry in the App Store where the developer web site is another tap away.

[image]

Comment: Tapping "applications" doesn't do anything on my device. It's an iPhone SE with iOS 10.3

Comment: iPhone SE clearly has 64 architecture in the processor - I wonder if it rolled out in 10.3.1 instead of 10.3 @kjubus. Any chance you can update to the current build of 10.3 ? Also, a clean reboot of the device can help if the settings app gets mixed up and doesn't compile the list as shown above.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work either on 10.3 or 10.3.1.

If you can do it, could you install the IPELA app yourself and let me know? it's free on app store.